# String Equality, How many objects when 3 variables point to 1 reference

Tags: java

How many objects are in the following code fragment?

```
String s1, s2, s3 = "hello";
```

Comment: There is nothing to do with string equality in this question.

Comment: What have you tried yourself to research this?

Comment: i didn't understand your question _how many objects when 3 variables point to 1 reference?_

Comment: @Swati "when 3 variables point to 1 reference" only s3 variable hold reference to `"hello"`, rest are uninitialized.

Comment: one more reason not to use this style of declaration... prefer having one variable per line (side-note, it wouldn't matter if all 3 were holding the same reference, still only one instance/object) (and the variable isn't pointing to a reference, it is holding the reference; pointing to the object)

Answer (score 3):

**Only `s3` is initialized.**

You can try to call one of the methods (e.g. `length()`) and compile this code:

```
String s1, s2, s3 = "hello";

// Error here
System.out.println(s1.length());

// Error here
System.out.println(s2.length());

// Correct one
System.out.println(s3.length());
```

It's equals to write:

```
String s1;
String s2;
String s3 = "hello";
```

Comment: In theory, shouldn't there be 3 and just 1 is initialized?